# TCP/IP connection over global internet connection (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp, p2p

Essentially I've been trying to relay messages between two computers using c/c++ using standard socket programming. Everything works fine on LAN. The issue is making the connection using something like external ip address. I searched online and saw methods that mention ensuring the router is configured for "port forwarding". However, I was wondering how do peer to peer communication apps like qTox overcome this barrier, since they do not require that technical step? To summarize, how can I connect two sockets between two computers that are NOT on the same network?

Comment: They use UDP/TCP Hole Punching.

Comment: I simply tried searching Google for "UDP Hole Punching", and got immediate results. Did you try doing that yourself?

Comment: I have. I was looking to see if there are any recommendations that would narrow my search.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "recommendations". The very first hit for me is a Wikipedia article that gives a step-by-step description of how it works.

Comment: https://bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/index.html

Comment: As mentioned, UDP hole punching is a solution for peer-to-peer communication without port forwarding. In order to avoid encouraging an XY problem, though, it should also be mentioned that simply having a server sitting in the middle through which the two clients communicate (a middleman) may also be a solution to the underlying problem. The server's local IP would have to be port-forwarded within its network, but neither of the clients would require this. There are pros and cons to both methods.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. They have been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some methods we usually use to solve the problem.

1. If you can use a server in WLAN as relay or central controller, it's quite simple. The computers connect to the server, the server change messages for them and can do many more operations.
2. If you don't want to use a server, then here is a problem: NAT devices may drop those packets which haven't established a connection according to their type. Here are four types: full cone NAT, restricted NAT, port restricted NAT and symmetric NAT. And here are some methods for this circumstance

   2.1 Use NAT traversal algorithm, but they may not work well in symmetric NAT.

   2.2 Use STUN/TURN/ICE to realise NAT traverse, it's quite reliable but need to learn how to use them.